# Why do I intuitively seem to know the gender of inanimate objects?

Tags: gender, hindustani

***Note to the Responder***: This curiosity behind this question arose because of my (relative) proficiency in the Hindi language, but the answers need not be necessarily limited to it.
I am a complete noob with regards to linguistics, so please bear with any amateurish remarks I may make in my ignorance.

I am a native Hindi speaker, which like many other languages, *assigns a gender to inanimate objects*. I am aware that people who are monolingually educated in a tongue which does not have these characteristics struggle to learn gendered languages, like Hindi and French, and I can understand why they might feel so.

However, maybe because I'm a native Hindi speaker, I feel like I effortlessly **know** the gender of any inanimate object I can think of, even with the noun in question not necessarily being of the Hindi language. (Context: In the northern part of India where I'm from, a sort of merged tongue of Hindi and English is spoken, known colloquially as Hinglish). As an example, let's say I take a few nouns from the English language, which I selected off the top of my head:

- Betelgeuse
- Spaceship
- Earphones

I just intuitively **know** that Betelgeuse is male, a spaceship is female and the earphones are male in the Hindi tongue, while these nouns do not necessarily have an equivalent Hindi word. To some of my non-Hindi friends who are native in an agendered language, I am unable to explain why a spaceship *seems* female, because while it seems obvious to me (atleast linguistically), there seems to be no good reason for it being so, and no universal rules for assigning gender.

What linguistic or cognitive factors contribute to my ability to intuitively assign gender to inanimate objects?

I'm eager to learn from linguists and experts in language acquisition. While I've shared my experiences, I know there may be established theories and research on this topic. I welcome insights into the cognitive processes or cultural factors that influence gender assignment in languages like Hindi and French. If you know of relevant studies or resources, please share.

Comment: This is actually quite a good question. In many cases, morphological clues help (e.g., words ending in _-o_ being masculine and those in _-a_ feminine in Spanish); other times, especially with loanwords, an existing native equivalent provides a hint (perhaps _Betelgeuse_ is masculine because the Hindi words for ‘star’ are masculine); or sometimes one gender is just generally the default. But sometimes, even though there doesn’t seem to be anything specific in favour of any particular gender for a new (or even fictitious) word, native speakers will overwhelmingly agree on one.

Comment: German has three genders and native speakers are significantly more likely to agree on what the gender of nonsense words would be (or is, if you prefer -- gender is a slippery business and so is modality).

Comment: According to the WALS, every language with grammatical gender has very well-defined rules for determining the gender of a noun, and the rules are not very large (so nothing like Risch's Algorithm involved).

Comment: Source that for every language if said language grammatical gender on nouns then it also has well-defined and not very large rules for gender assignment: https://wals.info/chapter/32

Comment: Note that *things* do not have genders, *nouns* do. For example, what is the gender of “stone” in Latin? It depends on whether you call it _lapis_ (masculine), _rupes_ (feminine) or _saxum_ (neuter).

Comment: @HolyKnowing. " but for languages where careful research has been undertaken, gender is always predictable from a set of assignment rules, for at least 85% of the noun inventory ". This is manifestly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://old.amu.ac.in/emp/studym/100009224.pdf) gives some heuristics for predicting gender in Hindi. It doesn't purport to work 100% of the time, but a number of the rules are historically credible, and I have seen similar heuristics for predicting gender in other Indo-European languages. Your point about spaceship isn't entirely clear – the internet tells me the word is अंतरिक्ष यान which I think is masculine (following the above rule). Perhaps you have another Hindi expression in mind for "spaceship". Now, if you mean you have an intuition that "spaceship" is feminine in English, that follows a similar "rule" that one refers to ships as "she", suggesting feminine gender (though we don't really have grammatical gender in English).

Comment: I think the meaning was that if they use the English word _spaceship_ in a Hindi (or Hinglish) sentence, then they would assign (Hindi) female gender to it. My initial thought was that this might be due to bleed from actual Hindi words (similar to how I instinctively know that if I were to use _spaceship_ in a Scandiwegian sentence, it would be neuter because the indigenous words for ‘ship’ are neuter), but all the words I could find for (space)ship were masculine, so that wouldn’t be it.

Comment: Hindu नाव (nāv "boat") is feminine, as is the reconstructed root noun, but it seems that Sanskrit had two reflexes, fem. नौ (nau) and masc. नाव (nāva), which continues the full grade (I think) and has flipped gender; following wiktionary: [ship](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ship)

Comment: I have a further question. My other language is Norwegian, and this is a gendered language like Hindi is. If we are able to intuit genders according to these historically credible rules, then why can they flip around dichronically? For example, "skip" and "båt", meaning "ship" and "boat", are neuter and masculine in Norwegian. But in German, it is the other way round. And it seems like any body part that's masculine in Norwegian, like shoulder or kidney, is feminine in German. This kind of thing seems to point to the possibility that what you're describing is not the full picture or something.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What do you mean? The Scandiwegian words for spaceship I know are romskip and (less common) romfartøy; both are neuter

Comment: @Lorraine Exactly. I didn’t think of _fartøj_ ‘vessel’, but the fact that _skip_ is neuter is (presumably) the reason why _spaceship_ would also almost certainly be treated as neuter. For example, imagine you’re describing something in a computer game, you might say, “Man flyr rundt i et sånt _spaceship_”, but I at least would never say, “Man flyr rundt i en sånn _spaceship_”. **Edit:** Oh, you meant the reference to masculine words – that was referring to the _Hindi_ words for ‘ship’ I could find.

Comment: As @JanusBahsJacquet pointed out, assigning gender to an English word in the Hindi language (Hinglish, so to speak) does not seem to relate much to translations. Most native speakers will agree that अंतरिक्ष यान is indisputably male (by intuitively using it in a sentence), while spaceship is indisputably female. The English words seem to behave as individual entities, not necessarily relating to their actual translations to Hindi (if those even exist). Ex: When thinking about the gender of a random English word, most can assign it effortlessly even if they don't know its Hindi translation.

Comment: अंतरिक्ष यान is not a real Hindi word and the only people who recognize it are invariably educated in English. Monolingual Hindi speakers have never heard this word in their life. In this learned word, gender has been assigned prescriptively to match Sanskrit. In words actually used by all Hindi speakers, the names of vehicles are feminine by default. They change to masculine if the vehicle is really big or does not work very well.

Comment: नाव does not seem like a Hindi word either. Hindi has a phonotactic rule prohibiting v word finally and monolingual speakers would not be able to pronounce नौ and नाव differently. People who do pronounce नाव with a v at the end are again, without exception, fluent in English which does allow v word finally.

Comment: The reasons for gender assignment in Hindi are entirely culturally motivated. Many of the same words in Punjabi are a different gender because in Punjabi culture the understanding of these concepts are viewed differently. Most Punjabis are bilingual in Hindi/Urdu and percieve it as a "womanly" language. So a word like rāh which is always masculine in Punjabi changes to feminine when they speak Hindi. I wish I could elaborate but the details of this are absolutely not understood yet.